# Magento 2 change urlkey and set custom product urlkey

Tags: magento2, product, url, url-rewrite, magento-2.0.7

I want to change my Magento 2 product urlkey and set something like `example.com/product-name/product-id` instead of `example.com/product-name.html`.

**Where do I have to change it while saving product from admin ?**

I found this file but it does not work .

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator.php
```

I changed in this file and then created a new product. Should I change another file?
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The URL key is generated by an Observer that uses the class you've mentionned:

`app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/Observer/ProductUrlKeyAutogeneratorObserver` :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var Product $product */
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $product->setUrlKey($this->productUrlPathGenerator->getUrlKey($product));
}
```

Then in the `ProductUrlGenerator` you have those two methods:

```
public function getUrlKey($product)
{
    return $product->getUrlKey() === false ? false : $this->prepareProductUrlKey($product);
}

protected function prepareProductUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
    return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() : $urlKey);
}
```

My suggestion to implement what you want would be to implement a plugin via a custom module

In your `di.xml` you can add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator">
        <plugin name="custom_url_generation" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomUrlGenerator"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in `Plugin\CustomUrlGenerator.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CustomUrlGenerator {

    public function beforeGetUrlKey(\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator $subject, $product)
    {
         $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
         if ($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null) {
              $product->setUrlKey($product->getName() . "/" . $product->getId());
         }
         return $product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but one problem is arise . when I print "$product->getId()" in beforegetUrlKey() function  it return null because in this function product will not saved . how to set product id in url key ? I also tried catalog_product_save_after but problem is when I use save() function in catalog_product_save_after observer page is infinite loading .not response from browser and not display product page

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I needed this code to add custom URL's to my webshop. The answer Raphael at Digital Pianism gave is correct, except for the `return $product;` statement. Using this will give an Intereceptor error.

To fix this, replace `return $product;` with `return ['getUrlKey' => $product];`

Answer (score 1):

Raphael at Digital Pianism was right. Looks like the class has been changed as of Magento 2.2.4 to return the string.

I solved it by using an around plugin and returning the $process.

```
public function aroundGetUrlKey(\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator $subject, callable $process, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $urlKey = $product ? $product->getUrlKey() : '';
    if ($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null) {
        $product->setUrlKey($product->getName() . "/" . $product->getId());
    }
    return $process($product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 transliter URL using filters that remove anything that is not alphanumeric. I started the same way using a plugin to go around the GetUrlKey, however, even if the url is saved with a slash in it, the generated entry in the core URL entry will have the slash removed.

I just submitted a pull request https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/17478 that should allow slashes and underscores in the URL rewrite. Let's see if it's accepted. But if so, then @JonShipman answer will work. If you're in a hurry you can take the pull request and create an override for the TranslitUrl filter.

Comment: I installed your custom url-key module on Magento 2.3.2 [ composer require werfu/magento2-url-key-mask ]. Works great with {{sku}}, but for {{brand}} it returns the attribute ID (like 535), instead if a string. Can you let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: @IvetaAllogenes let's not polute this thread, please open an issue on the repo (https://github.com/werfu/magento2-url-key-mask/issues) and detail your use case (is the attribute a drop-down, or straight text, etc).